# Can't connect to LocalDB SQL Server in PHP but able to connect via SSMS?

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection, relational-database, ssms

I have ssms v17.9 and sqllocaldb installed and I created an instance by executing sqlocaldb c LocalDB (I know shouldn't have named it this) in cmd

Versions:

`Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8)
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (13.0.1601.5)`

My Instance Info:

`Name:               LocalDB
Version:            13.0.1601.5
Shared name:
Owner:              DESKTOP-VEEPJ7N\HP
Auto-create:        No
State:              Running
Last start time:    11/2/2018 1:35:47 AM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#E4E686C1\tsql\query`

PHP code:

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "sales_dist_sys");
$serverName = "(LocalDB)\\LocalDB";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

I have checked the connection string and db name in SSMS in which it connects seamlessly but it returns $conn = null in php. What could be the possible reason(s)? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You has installed the ODBC and PHP driver?
Check that: 
ODBC Driver: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567
PHP driver for SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

You can to check this example the microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Regards.